# Minimum value of set in idiomatic Go

Tags: algorithm, go, set, idioms

How do I write a function that returns the minimum value of a set in go? I am not just looking for a solution (I know I could just initialize the min value when iterating over the first element and then set a boolean variable that I initialized the min value) but rather an idiomatic solution. Since go doesn't have native sets, assume we have a `map[Cell]bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps are the idiomatic way to implement sets in Go. Idiomatic code uses either bool or struct{} as the map's value type. The latter uses less storage, but requires a little more typing at the keyboard to use.

Assuming that the maximum value for a cell is `maxCell`, then this function will compute the min:

```
func min(m map[Cell]bool) Cell {
    min := maxCell
    for k := range m {
        if k < min {
            min = k
        }
    }
    return min
}
```

If Cell is a numeric type, then maxCell can be set to one of the [math constants](http://godoc.org/math#pkg-constants).

Any solution using a map will require a loop over the keys.

You can keep a [heap](http://godoc.org/container/heap) in addition to the map to find a minimum. This will require more storage and code, but can be more efficient depending on the size of the set and how often the minimum function is called.

Comment: If you use a sorted slice (sort on insertion), you don't have to loop to get min/max.

Comment: Thanks. The math constants was what I was looking for. It's unfortunate, that go doesn't have a min function for integers so that you can just write min = math.min(min, k). Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach and depending on how big your set is, using a self-sorting-slice can be more efficient:

```
type Cell uint64

type CellSet struct {
    cells []Cell
}

func (cs *CellSet) Len() int {
    return len(cs.cells)
}

func (cs *CellSet) Swap(i, j int) {
    cs.cells[i], cs.cells[j] = cs.cells[j], cs.cells[i]
}

func (cs *CellSet) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return cs.cells[i] < cs.cells[j]
}

func (cs *CellSet) Add(c Cell) {
    for _, v := range cs.cells {
        if v == c {
            return
        }
    }
    cs.cells = append(cs.cells, c)
    sort.Sort(cs)
}

func (cs *CellSet) Min() Cell {
    if cs.Len() > 0 {
        return cs.cells[0]
    }
    return 0
}

func (cs *CellSet) Max() Cell {
    if l := cs.Len(); l > 0 {
        return cs.cells[l-1]
    }
    return ^Cell(0)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/5d0lSuHwOL) // this is a test file, copy it to set_test.go and run `go test -bench=. -benchmem -v`

```
BenchmarkSlice                20          75385089 ns/op             104 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMap                  20          77541424 ns/op             158 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkSliceAndMin          20          77155563 ns/op             104 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMapAndMin             1        1827782378 ns/op            2976 B/op          8 allocs/op
```